# MongoDB - Somar documentos que possuem determinado valor, dentro de um array

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express.js, mongoose

Olá, obrigado pela atenção. Se eu tiver deixado alguma dúvida, por favor, me avisem.

Eu encontrei um problema que esta me deixando louco. Eu tenho a seguinte coleção:

```
{
    "_id": "5d752c544f4f1c0f1c93eb23",
    "address": {
        "coordinates": { "latitude": -21, "longitude": 21 },
        "zip_code": "15775000",
        "state": "são paulo",
        "city": "são paulo",
        "neighborhood": "vila serraria",
        "street": "rua mendez cunha",
        "number_house": "550",
        "createdAt": "2019-09-08T16:29:08.809Z"
    },
    "excluded": false,
    "name": "estacionamento um",
    "cnpj": "24939598479",
    "telephone": { "ddd": 22, "number": "992658386" },
    "parkingSpace": [
        {
            "description": {
                "accessibility": true,
                "covered": false,
                "vehicle_type": false,
                "services": false
            },
            "excluded": false,
            "avalible": true,
            "_id": "5d752cf54f4f1c0f1c93eb27",
            "value": 2.2,
            "name": "vg001",
            "createdAt": "2019-09-08T16:31:49.752Z",
            "updatedAt": "2019-09-09T01:18:09.403Z"
        },
        {
            "description": {
                "accessibility": true,
                "covered": false,
                "vehicle_type": false,
                "services": false
            },
            "excluded": false,
            "avalible": true,
            "_id": "5d75339bc411423a9c14ac52",
            "value": 3.5,
            "name": "vg002",
            "createdAt": "2019-09-08T17:00:11.167Z",
            "updatedAt": "2019-09-08T17:00:11.167Z"
        },
        {
            "description": {
                "accessibility": true,
                "covered": false,
                "vehicle_type": false,
                "services": false
            },
            "excluded": false,
            "avalible": true,
            "_id": "5d75aeb8821ce95a74749c95",
            "value": 2.3,
            "name": "vg003",
            "createdAt": "2019-09-09T01:45:28.772Z",
            "updatedAt": "2019-09-09T01:45:28.772Z"
        },
        {
            "description": {
                "accessibility": true,
                "covered": false,
                "vehicle_type": false,
                "services": false
            },
            "excluded": false,
            "avalible": false,
            "_id": "5d75aec7821ce95a74749c96",
            "value": 3,
            "name": "vg004",
            "createdAt": "2019-09-09T01:45:43.089Z",
            "updatedAt": "2019-09-10T01:15:41.075Z"
        }
    ],
    "qualification": [],
    "createdAt": "2019-09-08T16:29:08.813Z",
    "updatedAt": "2019-09-10T01:15:41.075Z",
    "__v": 1
},
{
    "_id": "5d7706b60d354b72388a38f4",
    "address": {
        "coordinates": { "latitude": -21, "longitude": 21 },
        "zip_code": "15775000",
        "state": "são paulo",
        "city": "são paulo",
        "neighborhood": "vila serraria",
        "street": "rua mendez",
        "number_house": "550",
        "createdAt": "2019-09-10T02:13:10.073Z"
    },
    "excluded": false,
    "name": "estacionamento dois",
    "cnpj": "24939598475",
    "telephone": { "ddd": 17, "number": "991848123" },
    "parkingSpace": [
        {
            "description": {
                "accessibility": true,
                "covered": false,
                "vehicle_type": false,
                "services": false
            },
            "excluded": false,
            "avalible": true,
            "_id": "5d77078a5173bb63bc87b7ca",
            "value": 3,
            "name": "vg004",
            "createdAt": "2019-09-10T02:16:42.335Z",
            "updatedAt": "2019-09-10T02:16:42.335Z"
        }
    ],
    "qualification": [],
    "createdAt": "2019-09-10T02:13:10.079Z",
    "updatedAt": "2019-09-10T02:16:42.335Z",
    "__v": 1
}
```

Note que há dois documentos simbolizando um estacionamento, onde cada, possui um array, chamado **parkingSpaces**, para registrar os documentos de vagas do estacionamento.

O primeiro documento possui 4 vagas não excluídas, sendo assim, com a propriedade **excluded: false** e o segundo, possui apenas uma vaga, que também não esta excluída.

Eu preciso somar a quantidade de vagas do estacionamento **_id: 5d752c544f4f1c0f1c93eb23**, que possua o valor **false** na propriedade **excluded**

Por enquanto, eu cheguei até aqui:

```
 const registeredParkingSpaces = await Parking.aggregate([
        { $unwind: '$parkingSpace' },
        { $match: { 'parkingSpace.excluded': false } },
        {
            $group: {
                _id: parking_id,
                total: { $sum: 1 }
            }
        }
 ]);
```

Mas acaba me retornando a quantidade dos dois estacionamentos, independente do **_id** :/

Resultado:

```
{
  "message": [
    {
      "_id": "5d752c544f4f1c0f1c93eb23",
      "total": 5
    }
  ]
}
```

Eu agradeço pela atenção.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Espero que ajude..

```
var parking_id = '5d752c544f4f1c0f1c93eb23';
db.parking.aggregate([
  { 
      $match: { 
          '_id': parking_id

      } 

  },
  {
        $project:{

            parkingTotal:{
                $sum:{$map:{
                    input:'$parkingSpace',
                    as: 'p',
                    in:{
                         $add:{ $cond: { if: '$$p.excluded', then: 0, else: 1 } }
                    }
                }
            }}
        }
    }
])
```

Resultado:

```
{
  "_id" : "5d752c544f4f1c0f1c93eb23",
   "parkingTotal" : 4
}
```